# BigDecimal from json loses precision

Tags: javascript, java, json, angularjs, bigdecimal

The network call shows that the backend is sending this:

```
"uom" : "EA",
"qty" : 1.123456789012345678
```

but when it reaches the frontend, using console.log:

```
{ 
  qty: 1.1234567890123457, 
  uom: "EA"
}
```

why is the javascript losing the last digit or truncating the number?

The number is represented using a BigDecimal in java. The frontend use AngularJs framework, makes a GET call to the backend requesting a JSON.

Comment: For exhaustive details see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). If you need it to be exact don't use (regular) numbers.

Comment: For what purpose do you need finer precision than 17 significant digits?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript floating point numbers hold 64 bits of precision, similar to a `double` in Java.  If you have to use BigDecimal in Java to extend beyond that level of precision, you'll need to do something similar in Javascript to extend beyond its similar boundary.  The NPM package js-big-decimal is probably your best bet and you can transfer the values as strings in JSON to prevent JSON.parse from interpreting them as Number.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I found that adding

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
public getQty(){
   return this.qty;
}
```

to the java domain object solves the issue.

Comment: You're missing a return type.